# Control gdm's policy of restarting X

Tags: xorg, configuration, x-server, gdm

I'm on a system where gdm is used for the display manager; and I have root access (though it's not "my" machine per se).

Now, for some reason which is not the point of this question, the server fails to start; and gdm tried to restart it, again and again - preventing me from using even the virtual consoles. Alternatively - maybe it's systemd that's restarting gdm? I don't know.

How can I tell gdm not to try a restart at all, or alternatively, give up after A fixed number of attempts? I can't find anything relevant in `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf`.

Comment: Are you sure that it's gdm restarting X and not systemd / sysvinit / something_else restarting gdm ad nauseam?

Comment: @pizdelect: I'm  not 100% sure actually.